# Difference between two equal valve tubes

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, power-amplifier

Is there any difference in "Plate Voltage"/"Plate Current" curve between two real vacuum tubes 12ax7?

Comment: Yes. No two individual components on this earth are identical! So, the question is: How much difference can your circuit tolerate, and will two tubes stay within that? You should ask **that** question, including a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Thanks, i. e. I can't simply replace one valve in my old amplifier with equal new without circuit tuning, right?

Comment: That **should** work, as someone *designed* that amplifier to be actually producible – which means that the factory gets a load of valves and plugs these into amplifier sockets and expects those to work. It might be necessary to adjust a few trimmers afterwards, but I'd expect an amplifier to be designed with that tolerance in mind.

Comment: But then again, there might be several decades that your amplifier including the old valve aged due to usage, but your replacement valve didn't, so there's a fair bit of luck involved, but, again, chances are good.

Comment: @Marcus Müller But if I build my own "common-cathode" amplifier with one tube using standard "Plate Voltage"/"Plate Current" curve I'll get some bias point. Will the real bias point be different from that I calculate using equations? I think it will be!

Comment: yeah, within the tolerances of that tube; I don't really know any tube datasheets, but you'd go with the nominal curve, and design stuff, and then test whether it still works, for example, if your actual curve is 15% below or above!

Comment: For modern components, you'll get the tolerance straight from the data sheet; I don't know if that's always been the case. Anyway, things like transistors have tolerances, too, and for them you design amplifiers in a way where the absolute \$h_{fe}\$ isn't critical. I guess the same applies to tube amps: Anything with a feedback path can achieve a fixed amplification, given that the amplifying part's (in your case, the tube's) amplification is larger enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the manufacturing tolerances of vacuum tubes (valves) are quite wide (more than ±20%) and not often specified as they are in some other components.  You will note on the datasheets that the graphs are typically labeled "average characteristics", meaning they show average values taken from a large number of production devices.  Additionally, parameters can drift as the device ages.

There are a few things that are commonly done in designing circuits around them:

- Just as with bipolar junction transistors (which can have a wide range of β values), the biasing network can be designed so that the circuit is immune to the variations within a range.  In a common-cathode amplifier, this usually means biasing with a cathode resistor as opposed to a voltage reference.  A device with above-average transconductance will self-bias to a lower grid voltage.
- In some circuits (e.g. the output stage of push-pull audio power amplifiers), an *adjustable* bias is built in.  When tubes are replaced the grid bias voltage is set with a potentiometer for the appropriate plate current.
- Tubes can be sorted into tolerance ranges after manufacturing for applications that are more sensitive to parameter variations.  Sometimes they are matched in pairs for push-pull amplifier use.

Answer (score 0):

12AX7's are cathode biased, the circuit biases itself and is not adjustable, to change the bias point you have to change to circuit.

Since it is biasing itself, you swap any 12AX7 for any other 12AX7 safely, no matter what the circuit, without tuning or biasing of any kind.

Or you can swap the 12AX7 with a 12AT7, 12AU7, 12AV7, 12AY7, 12AZ7, 5751, 5814 and others if you want to change the gain, all without ever having to worry about the bias.

Comment: This is not correct.  Although most circuits using 12AX7s do use cathode bias it is not an inherent feature of the tube itself.  12AX7s are not biased at all until they're placed in a circuit.